# PostgreSQL - using group by sum as input to function for creating additional column in a view

Tags: sql, postgresql, plpgsql

I am new to PostgreSQL and this might not really be the best way to achieve my result, but here is what i am trying.

I have a table called `meteo` and another called `areas`. `meteo` has values of measured precipitation at different stations, and the stations are grouped into areas identified by `id`s.

`areas` has the same `id`s found in `meteo` and their positions/geometries.

**meteo**

```
station precipitation   area_id
1       40              1
2       60              1
3       50              2
4       30              2
```

**areas**

```
zone_id geom
1       "THE GEOMETRY"
2       "THE GEOMETRY"
```

I need to create a view that aggregate all stations from `meteo` that have the same `id`, join to `areas` by `id` and SUM all precipitation for those areas.

Other than this, I also need an additional column in my view that tells me the `magnitude` of the SUM precipitation in each area, based on a classification.

I can create the view without the extra `magnitude` column, and I sincerely do not know how to move on.

Here is how I create my view for now:

```
create view my_view (area_id, precipitation, geom)
as select area_id, precipitation, geom from
    (select area_id, sum(precipitation) precipitation
    from meteo
    group by area_id) as mt,
areas areas
where zone_id = mt.area_id;
```

Then, I have created a function called `calculatePrecipitationMagnitude` that I would like to use in my view to calculate the additional column I need.

```
create or replace function calculatePrecipitationMagnitude(precipitation float4)
    returns text as $$
    begin
        if abs(precipitation) >= 100 then
            return 'level3';
        elsif abs(precipitation) >= 50 AND abs(precipitation) < 100 then
            return 'level2';
        elsif abs(precipitation) < 50 then
            return 'level1';
        else
            return 'level0';
        end if;
    end;
    $$
    LANGUAGE PLPGSQL;
```

The function seems to work fine but I am stuck in how to use it inside my view declaration.

Final view would be something like:

**my_view**

```
area_id precipitaion    geom            magnitude
1       100             "THE GEOMETRY"  level3
2       80              "THE GEOMETRY"  level2
```

I am using PostgreSQL 10.

Comment: You are complicating the things. I feel function is not required at all. please add the table structure and sample data with sample output of view. it will give us a better understanding

Comment: I have just provided some samples.

Comment: in your function from where you are getting `inc`. it will throw error

Comment: There is no need to use a function for this, a simple `CASE WHEN` should suffice: `CASE WHEN ABS(SUM(precipitation)) >= 100 THEN 'level3' WHEN...` etc

Comment: corrected, that was a typo

Comment: Well, at least to me it improves readibility. If I want I can simply jump to my function definition and change it as needed instead of finding the CASE part in my query. Would using a function be discouraged in these cases?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Considering both of your queries are working fine you can write your view definition as

```
create view my_view 
as select area_id, precipitation, geom, calculatePrecipitationMagnitude(precipitation) "magnitude" from
    (select area_id, sum(precipitation) precipitation
    from meteo
    group by area_id) as mt,
areas.geom
where areas.area_id = mt.area_id;
```

Comment: thanks! that was simple, I tried many combination but I probably missed the alias "magnitude" to get it work.

Answer (score 1):

I don't see how your current view is working.  Two obvious errors are:

- `area.geom` is undefined (or does not refer to the `area` table.
- `area_id` is ambiguous in the `select`.

For your problem, I would suggest:

```
create view my_view as
    select m.area_id, m.precipitation, a.geom,
           calculatePrecipitationMagnitude(m.precipitation float4) as magnitude
    from (select area_id, sum(precipitation) as precipitation
          from meteo
          group by area_id
         ) m join
         areas a
         on a.area_id = m.area_id;
```

Notes:

- The second table should be `areas`, not `areas.geom`.
- All columns should be qualified in a query that references multiple tables.  In your version, `area_id` in the `select` is ambiguous.
- You don't need to list the column names for a view, if they are defined in the `select`.  I prefer defining them in the `select` -- easier to maintain.

Comment: You are right but mine were not the exact table names and columns I have. I have used just random names because I did not want to use the real tables I am working on. Will update my question to make it work if anybody else is interested in a similar situation.

Comment: Corrected, now it should work. Anyway, thanks for the notes, especially the last one. It really helped me clarifying some mistakes and best practices.

Comment: I know it's late, but if you could still answer, what would be the way not to list the column names for my view when there is `calculatePrecipitationMagnitude(m.precipitation float4) as magnitude` that is calculated "outside" the subquery?

Comment: got it: `select m.*, a.geom, calculatePrecipitationMagnitude(m.precipitation float4) as magnitude`